# Jetpack Compose: Image alignment after image scaling

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have Compose function with the Image:

```
Image(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().scale(1f),
    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.background),
    contentDescription = null,
    contentScale = ContentScale.None,
    alignment = BiasAlignment(1f, -1f)
)
```

`BiasAlignment(1f, -1f)` - means that image content (which is bigger than screen) will be align at the top-right side, this works right.

But, when I scale the image by half:

```
Image(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().scale(2f),
    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.background),
    contentDescription = null,
    contentScale = ContentScale.None,
    alignment = BiasAlignment(1f, -1f)
)
```

The alignment works not correctly, with some offsets, see the visualization of issue:
[image: Actual results and Expected result (dotted line)]

I guess, I need to play with some scale factor, something like this: `BiasAlignment(1f * scaleFactorX, -1f * scaleFactorY)`, the question is how to calculate them?

Comment: The coefficient - this is not just using image scale factor, for example here the output with `BiasAlignment(2f, -2f)` https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB00Z.png

Comment: What I want to achieve - https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Jmw.png

Answer (score 0):

calculate the new width and height then use the Modifier.size() to set the new width and height

```
@Composable
fun ScaledImage() {
    val image: Painter = painterResource(R.drawable.background)

    val imageWidth = image.intrinsicSize.width
    val imageHeight = image.intrinsicSize.height

    val scaleFactor = 2f
    val newWidth = imageWidth * scaleFactor
    val newHeight = imageHeight * scaleFactor

    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .size(newWidth.dp, newHeight.dp),
        painter = image,
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.None,
        alignment = BiasAlignment(1f, -1f)
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answering. Yes, I've tried that trick before, the issue with this approach is that image stay same after `.size(newWidth, newHeight)`, I think this is because this changes just size of composable box, not the content

Comment: I can share the `background.png` for the experiments, but this can be any image  with bigger than screen resolution with some pattern to see image positioning

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to scale image:

`contentScale = FixedScale(2f)`

Alignment works correctly with scaled image:

```
Image(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.background),
    contentDescription = null,
    contentScale = FixedScale(2f),
    alignment = BiasAlignment(1f, -1f)
)
```